# Physical interpretation of time constancy in damped harmonic oscillator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, time, friction, harmonic-oscillator, frequency

I know that one can mathematically derive and prove that in a damped oscillator (without external driving) the time period of oscillations is a constant. But how can one physically interpret as to why should the time period of oscillations be constant even though there is a resistive medium and decreasing amplitude, meaning the amplitude of oscillations decrease exactly with growing time so as to give a constant time period. How can one explain this absolute miracle physically without the help of equations?

Answer (score 1):

The period of oscillation is only constant for the case of linear damping*$-$i.e., when the damping force is proportional to velocity.  There is no variation in damping with respect to amplitude or acceleration.  Therefore, throughout the entire oscillation, there will be a set proportion of energy dissipated by damping independent of amplitude or acceleration, yielding an "expected" influence on the periodicity of the event.

This gives a sense that the damping force is acting in harmony with the inertial and restorative forces (mass and spring), which it is, during oscillation for this case.  Hopefully this intuitively satisfies your question.

*Regarding nonlinearity, if you have a differential equation of the form

\begin{equation}
m\ddot{x} + c\dot{x}^n + kx = F(t)
\end{equation}
such that $n \ne 1$, i.e. the case of nonlinear damping, then the frequency dependence becomes a function of amplitude, $x(t)$, in addition to the inertial, damping, and restoring coefficients ($m$, $c$, and $k$).  Recall the (linear) damped frequency:

\begin{equation}
\omega_d = \sqrt{\frac{k(1 - \zeta^2)}{m}}
\end{equation}

This is only a function of $m$, $c$, and $k$, and it is a constant.  This means the frequency of damped oscillation does not change with respect to time.

Further reading: http://www.msc.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~phyexp/uploads/Oscillateurs%C3%89tranges/Quadratic_oscillations.pdf